# Flickers due to the background repaint despite BufferedReader

Tags: java, user-interface, background, flicker

I am currently working on a little 2D Game based on Super Mario Bros.
I'm using a Model-View-Controller-Pattern and i have a flickering issue in my Panel (extending JPanel). My blocks and everything but Mario are constantly flashing and i don't know why. I tried to do a BufferedReader to fix the problem but it did not change anyhting, neither a smaller resolution background did.
I noticed that when i remove the background (and so we see traces left behind Mario), nothing flickers anymore but I can't let it like that...
Do you have any ideas of where the problems come ?

Thank you very much for your attention, I join the code of my GUI here.

PS: I'm new in java so please forgive my beginner code and problems :). Also, forgive my english. I can add any other part of my code if needed.

Note : level is my main model loop and there is different bonuses with differents effects on Mario as differents status like OnAir, etc.

**Window**

```
package GUI;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import model.Level;
import observable.Observator;

public class Window extends JFrame implements Observator{

public Panel pan;
Level level;

public Window(Level level){
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("Mario");
    setExtendedState(6);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setSize(level.cam.getHitboxx(),level.cam.getHitboxy());
    setResizable(false);
    this.level = level;
    this.pan = new Panel(level);
    setContentPane(this.pan);
    }

public void update(Level level){
this.level = level;
this.pan.setLevel(this.level);
this.pan.render();
this.pan.paintComponent(getGraphics());
}

public Level getLevel() {
return level;
 }

public void setLevel(Level level) {
this.level = level;
}
```

}

**Panel**

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import model.Edge;
import model.Level;
import model.Mario;
import model.StaticEntity;

public class Panel extends JPanel{

protected Level level;
private Image marioNormalLeftImg;
private Image marioNormalRightImg;
private Image marioJumpingRightImg;
private Image marioJumpingLeftImg;
private Image marioCrouchRightImg;
private Image marioCrouchLeftImg;
private Image marioDeadImg;
private Image backgroundImg;
private Image rightGoombaImg;
private Image leftGoombaImg;
private Image brickImg;
private Image CoinImg;
private Image gameOverImg;
private Image winImg;
private Image WeedGIF;
private Image WeedBonusImg;
private Image metalShroomImg;
private Image lifeShroomImg;
private Image shroomImg;
private Image marioGIF;
private Image bonusBrickImg;
private Image groundImg;

public Panel(Level level){
    try
    {

      this.marioNormalLeftImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Mario_NormalLeft.png"));
      this.marioNormalRightImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Mario_NormalRight.png"));
      this.marioJumpingRightImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Mario_JumpRight.png"));
      this.marioJumpingLeftImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Mario_JumpLeft.png"));
      this.marioCrouchRightImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Mario_CrouchRight.png"));
      this.marioCrouchLeftImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Mario_CrouchLeft.png"));
      this.marioDeadImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Mario_Dead.png"));
      this.backgroundImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Background2.png"));
      this.rightGoombaImg = ImageIO.read(new File("goomba1.png"));
      this.leftGoombaImg = ImageIO.read(new File("goomba2.png"));
      this.brickImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Brick_Block.png"));
      this.bonusBrickImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Bonus_Block.png"));
      this.CoinImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Coin1.png"));
      this.gameOverImg = ImageIO.read(new File("GameOver.png"));
      this.winImg = ImageIO.read(new File("youwin.png"));
      this.WeedGIF = this.getToolkit().createImage("Weed_Background.gif");
      this.marioGIF = this.getToolkit().createImage("walkinggif.gif");
      this.WeedBonusImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Weed.png"));
      this.metalShroomImg = ImageIO.read(new File("metalShroom.png"));
      this.lifeShroomImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Green_Mushroom.png"));
      this.shroomImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Red_Mushroom.png"));
      this.groundImg = ImageIO.read(new File("ground_large.png"));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.level = level;

}


public void setLevel(Level level){
this.level = level;}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    if(this.level.getTHCratio()>0){g.drawImage(this.WeedGIF, 0, 0, this.level.cam.getHitboxx(),  this.level.cam.getHitboxy(), this);
    }
    else{g.drawImage(this.backgroundImg, 0, 0,  this.level.cam.getHitboxx(),  this.level.cam.getHitboxy(), this);}
    this.paintMario(g);

    for(int i = 0;i<this.level.goombas.size();i++){
    if(this.level.goombas.get(i)!=null){this.paintGoomba(g, i);}}

    for(int i = 0;i<this.level.edges.size();i++){
        if(this.level.edges.get(i)!=null&&this.level.edges.get(i).visible){
            if(this.level.edges.get(i).type == "Normal"){
                drawComponent(this.level.edges.get(i),this.brickImg,0,g);
            }
            else if(this.level.edges.get(i).type == "Ground"){drawComponent(this.level.edges.get(i),this.groundImg,0,g);}
            else{drawComponent(this.level.edges.get(i),this.bonusBrickImg,0,g);}
        }       
    }
 for(int i = 0;i<this.level.bonus.size();i++){
        if(this.level.bonus.get(i)!=null){
            if(this.level.bonus.get(i).getClass().getName() == "model.Coin"){
            drawComponent(this.level.bonus.get(i),this.CoinImg,0,g);}
            else if (this.level.bonus.get(i).getClass().getName() == "model.WeedBonus"){
                drawComponent(this.level.bonus.get(i),this.WeedBonusImg,0,g);
            }
            else if (this.level.bonus.get(i).getClass().getName() == "model.MetalShroom"){
                drawComponent(this.level.bonus.get(i),this.metalShroomImg,0,g);
            }
            else if (this.level.bonus.get(i).getClass().getName() == "model.LifeShroom"){
                drawComponent(this.level.bonus.get(i),this.lifeShroomImg,0,g);
            }
            else if (this.level.bonus.get(i).getClass().getName() == "model.Shroom"){
                drawComponent(this.level.bonus.get(i),this.shroomImg,0,g);
            }
 }
 }

 Font police = (new Font("Mario Kart DS", Font.PLAIN, 30));
 if (police == null) {police = (new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 30));}
 g.setFont(police);
 g.setColor(Color.white);
 g.drawString("coins  " + String.valueOf(this.level.player.getCoins()), 1000, 50);
 g.drawString("score  " + String.valueOf(this.level.player.getScore()), 1000, 100);
 g.drawString("lives  " + String.valueOf(this.level.player.getLives()), 1000, 150);

 if(level.player.getLives() == 0){
     this.backgroundImg = this.gameOverImg;}
 if(this.level.player.getScore() == 200*level.goombas.size() + 100*level.bonus.size()){this.backgroundImg = this.winImg;this.leftGoombaImg = null;this.rightGoombaImg = null;this.brickImg = null;this.level.mario.setPosx(3000);this.level.mario.setPosy(3000);this.CoinImg = null;}           

}


public void paintMario(Graphics g){
    String statusName = this.level.mario.getStatus().getName();
    boolean goingRight = this.level.mario.getSpeedx()>=0;
    if(statusName == "OnAir"){
        if(goingRight){drawComponent(this.level.mario,this.marioJumpingRightImg,0,g);               
        }else{drawComponent(this.level.mario,this.marioJumpingLeftImg,0,g);}
    }
    else if(statusName == "DEAD"){
        drawComponent(this.level.mario,this.marioDeadImg,0,g);              
    }
    else if(statusName == "Crouch"){if(goingRight){drawComponent(this.level.mario,this.marioCrouchRightImg,0,g);            
    }else{drawComponent(this.level.mario,this.marioCrouchLeftImg,0,g);}}
    else{
        if(goingRight){drawComponent(this.level.mario,this.marioNormalRightImg,0,g);}
        else{drawComponent(this.level.mario,this.marioNormalLeftImg,0,g);}
    }
}

public void paintGoomba(Graphics g, int i){
    boolean goingRight = this.level.goombas.get(i).getSpeedx()>=0;
    if(goingRight){drawComponent(this.level.goombas.get(i),this.rightGoombaImg,10,g);}
    else{drawComponent(this.level.goombas.get(i),this.leftGoombaImg,10,g);}
}

private Image bufferImage = null;
private void gameRender()
{
    if(bufferImage == null)
    {
        bufferImage = createImage(1200, 800);
    }

    Graphics dbg = bufferImage.getGraphics();
    this.paintComponent(dbg);

}

private void gamePainting()
{
    Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
    if((g != null) && (bufferImage != null))
    {
        g.translate(0,0);
        g.drawImage(bufferImage, 0,  0,  null);
        g.dispose();
    }
}

public void render() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.gameRender();
    this.gamePainting();

}
public void drawComponent(StaticEntity obj, Image img,int shapeCorrector,Graphics g){
    if(this.level.cam.isOnHitbox(obj.getPosx(),obj.getPosy(),obj.getHitboxx(),obj.getHitboxy())){
        g.drawImage(img, obj.getPosx()-shapeCorrector-this.level.cam.getPosx(), obj.getPosy()-shapeCorrector-this.level.cam.getPosy(),  obj.getHitboxx()+shapeCorrector,  obj.getHitboxy()+shapeCorrector, null);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Do call `super.painComponent`
- Don't use `getGraphics`, it can be null and can be overridden by the paint sub system
- There's no need for the `gameRender` method, Swing components are already double buffered.

You seem to think you can control the paint process in a Swing. Swing uses a passive painting process, which means that a paint update may occur at anytime for any reason, many times, without your involvement.

You can request an update using `repaint`, but it's up to the paint sub system to schedule and the actually perform the update when it takes it should be done

Take a look at

- [Performing Custom Paining](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

for more details

Get rid of your `gameRender` and `gamePaint` methods and simply call `repaint` on the panel when you want to update its output

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I deleted gameRender and gamePaint methods and tried to do what you adviced, but i don't really know where i should place those methods and which arguments use, i'm really not familiar with the repaint and i didn't understand how to apply the explanations of the links you gave me... I tried to put a repaint() in the update method of window where i deleted

this.pan.render();
this.pan.paintComponent(getGraphics());
but now the model run but nothing appears on the JFrame... So what do i need to do ? place a super.PaintComponent ? where and with which arguments ?

Comment: First of all, read the linked tutorials.  You don't control the paint process.  You can simply call `repaint` on `Panel` to request that the component be repainted.  At some time in the future `paintComponent` will be called, when it is, you simply repaint the entire scene.  Call `super.paintComponent` first, before you do anything else, this will eliminate possible dirty paints or paint artefacts

Comment: @user3630007 You may also consider taking a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619540/java-thread-and-graphics2d/23620125#23620125) which presents a simple implementation of a MCV implementation for animating a simple object

Comment: So i did what you advised and i thought i did it wrong but actually all was working fine except i didn't see it. When i run the programm, a frame open with nothing painted on it. I must resize the frame and then all the components appear and all is working fine... Do you know what is the probleme and if this is possible to run properly the game without be forced to resize ? Thank you

Comment: Most likely you called setVisible before you finished building the UI. If possible, call setVisible last or call revalidate on the frame to force it to update the layout

Comment: I called it last and it fixed the problem ! Thank you very much my game is perfect (if i can say so) thanks to you !