# Java thread and graphics2d

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent

i need a hint how to make my program to work properly. I created a class that extends from JComponent. I also managed to make the whole panel of white colors. Now i am trying to make that my thread Wolf will be painted on the JCOmponent and will move one time. Unfortunately my code dont works and i think its because wolf is not being painted on the white board. How to change the program to make it work. I will be grateful for help.

```
public class Plansza extends JComponent implements ActionListener {

    static int   width = 500;
    static int   height = 500;
    Ellipse2D wolf;
    Ellipse2D hare;

    // size of frame n x m (width,height)
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(width,height);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        //draw a background
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);


    }   


    class Wilk implements Runnable{
        private int x;
        private int y;


        //when creating a thread we get a first position of wolf 
        Wilk(int posx, int posy){
            x=posx;
            y=posy;
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            //draw a wolf
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            wolf = new Ellipse2D.Double(x,y, 10, 10);
            g2.fill(wolf);
            }

        public void run() {
            x=x+5;
            y=y+5;
            repaint();

        }

    }



    public static void main( final String args[]) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Wilki vs Zajace");
        Plansza p = new Plansza();
        window.add(p);
        window.pack();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
    //  Timer t = new Timer(10,p);  //action listener referred to Plansza(1 cycle every 100miliseconds)
    //  t.start();
            Wilk wolf = new Wilk(10,10);
        Thread myWolf = new Thread(wolf);
        myWolf.start();
            }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
        }


}
```

Comment: Painting is done within (in this case) the JComponent's  paintComponent method. What you need is some way to tell your component what to paint,but can also be updated by your thread. Use some kind of model that can shared between the two. Also consider using a javax.swing.Timer instead of a Thread, this will help with possible synchronisation issues

Comment: i will need thread in the future,thats way i am trying to make it working for one thread.

Comment: what model do u meant?

Comment: This looks completely wrong. You are creating your mywolf thread inside the paintComponent method. I doubt you are looking to create a thread at every refresh (every time you move a window in front of your frame, for instance). Also your Wilk has a paintComponent methhod, but it is not a JComponent, it is a Runnable. That method will never be called.

Comment: A model is simply used to carry information, describes the the content and may provide means by which the content might be changed. If done right, this would decouple the view from thread/controller allowing you to change these components without needing to drastically alter them in most cases.also, remember, Swing is not thread save, this means you should not be attempting to change the UI from any thread other then the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: @MadProgrammer Did you look at his code? Your high level considerations are probably wasted here :)

Comment: @schmop Yep, I did, I considered it wrong on multiple levels and felt some direction would be more helpful over simply trying to correct what was already an attempt in the wrong direction

Comment: @MadProgrammer You sir, shall go to heaven

Comment: i made some changes. I just want to use repaint() method. I want to creater late lots of object of wilk and make them moving on the white board using paintCOmponent and repaint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by talking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for details about how painting is performed in Swing.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details about dealing with Swing a threads.

Basically, only a component on a displayed container will be painted.  This means that only your `Plansza` will be painted, but only when it's added to a (directly or otherwise) something like `JFrame` and the `JFrame` is made visible.

This means that `Wilk` can never be painted and therefore it's `paintComponent` method becomes somewhat pointless (in this context)

What you could use is some way to communicate what you want to paint from your `Wilk` (controller) to `Plansza` (view).  This is typically achieved via the use of some kind of model, which allows your controller to change it's state and your view to render that state.

For example...

[image: Bounce]

This is a basic demonstration of a [Model-Control-View](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) implementation.

The model drives the view and the controller drives the model.  In this way, so long as the contract of the model is meet, the various elements are independent of each other

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class PaintModel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PaintModel();
    }

    public PaintModel() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                MutableModel model = new DefaultModel();
                Controller controller = new Controller(model);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new View(model));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                controller.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public interface Model {

        public Rectangle getBounds();
        public Dimension getSize();
        public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);
        public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);

    }

    public interface MutableModel extends Model {

        public void update();

    }

    public class DefaultModel implements MutableModel {

        private final Dimension size = new Dimension(200, 200);
        private final Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(95, 95, 10, 10);

        private int xDelta = ((int) (Math.random() * 5)) + 1;
        private int yDelta = ((int) (Math.random() * 5)) + 1;

        private List<ChangeListener> changeListeners;

        public DefaultModel() {
            changeListeners = new ArrayList<>(25);
        }

        @Override
        public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
            changeListeners.add(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
            changeListeners.remove(listener);
        }

        protected void fireStateChanged() {
            if (changeListeners.size() > 0) {
                ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(this);
                Iterator<ChangeListener> it = changeListeners.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    ChangeListener listener = it.next();
                    listener.stateChanged(evt);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getSize() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public Rectangle getBounds() {
            return bounds;
        }

        @Override
        public void update() {
            bounds.x += xDelta;
            bounds.y += yDelta;
            if (bounds.x < 0) {
                bounds.x = 0;
                xDelta *= -1;
            } else if (bounds.x + bounds.width > size.width) {
                bounds.x = size.width - bounds.width;
                xDelta *= -1;
            }
            if (bounds.y < 0) {
                bounds.y = 0;
                yDelta *= -1;
            } else if (bounds.y + bounds.height > size.height) {
                bounds.y = size.height - bounds.height;
                yDelta *= -1;
            }
            fireStateChanged();
        }

    }

    public class Controller extends Thread {

        private MutableModel model;

        public Controller(MutableModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            setDaemon(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(40);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
                model.update();
            }
        }

    }

    public class View extends JComponent implements ChangeListener {

        private Model model;

        public View(Model model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.model.addChangeListener(this);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(model.getSize());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            Rectangle bounds = model.getBounds();
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g2d.drawOval(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In many modern languages the UI runs on the main thread, and you cannot modify it  (or you shouldn't at least) from another thread. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Although repaint(), and revalidate() are threadsafe and they have their own invokeAndWait, you MUST create the UI using something like this.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        createGUI();
     }
});
```

Therefore you are creating a paint wolf thread each time you paint the main panel.

Also Oracle suggest to call `super.paintComponent(g);`  in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html

I recommend you to read completely the Oracle Swing guide, and then try to modify the Flipper coin example to work as you want (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/concurrency/FlipperProject/src/concurrency/Flipper.java)

Comment: take a look at my code now. I made some changes. I want to use only repaint and make a lot of threads o Wilk class and i want them to be presented as blue objects which are moving on white board.